# Closing brace on new line brackets.io

Tags: javascript, coding-style, curly-braces

When I write JavaScript i like to have the opening brace on a new line.
When I create a for loop or if statement for example, I press the return key after the closing '(' then try to put '{' but it is indented like the picture and is really annoying. I know i can backspace the indent but sometimes I just keep typing and its annoying. Is there a way to change the settings to stop this? I had a look but couldnt find anything.

I know its indented as if statements dont need braces

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a setting specific to moving opening braces to the next line. However, there is user setting to disable auto-indent. You could try setting the following option to false instead:

```
// Automatically indent when creating a new block
"smartIndent": true,
```

Most JavaScript is written with the open brace on the same line as the new scope level (eg, function definition, iterator, conditional statement), so I suspect Brackets has this setting by default so that new code will be indented properly inside the block of your new level.

If you like the auto-indent as is, another thing you could do is hit shift+tab after hitting enter. This will reduce your tab level by one. When you hit enter again after typing the opening brace, the auto-intent will move to the correct level for the block.

Comment: I did try this, but then it removes all indenting, i dont think what im looking for is possible